# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 dx\int_0^x (x-y)^n f(y)dy.$

Tags: integration, limits

Let $f(x)$ be continuous over $[0,1]$. Evaluate

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 dx\int_0^x (x-y)^n f(y)dy.$$

## Solution

Since $f(x)$ is continuous over $[0,1]$,$f(x)$ is bounded, namely
$$\exists M>0, \forall x \in [0,1], |f(x)|\leq M.$$
Therefore
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_0^1 dx\int_0^x (x-y)^n f(y)dy\right|&\leq \int_0^1 \int_0^x|x-y|^n|f(y)|dydx~~~\textit{notice $0\leq y \leq x \leq 1$}\\
&\leq M\int_0^1 \int_0^x (x-y)^n dydx\\
&=M\cdot\frac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}\to 0 (n \to \infty).
\end{align*}
It follows that $$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_0^1 dx\int_0^x (x-y)^n f(y)dy=0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $0<y<x<1$ implies $|x-y| <1$ so $(x-y)^{n} \to 0$. The answer is $0$ by Dominated Convergence Theorem. The dominating function is $|f|$.

Second method. Pull out a bound for $|f|$ and note the $\int_0^{1} \int_0^{x} (x-y)^{n}dydx=\frac 1 { (n+2)(n+1)}$ by direct evaluation.

Comment: Please see my edit. Is it right? the same as your second method?

Comment: Yes, what you have done is correct.

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)$ is continuous and bounded and therefore attains a maximum absolute value. But this means that $|(x-y)^n f(x)| < c|(x-y)^n|$ for some $c$, and as $n \rightarrow \infty$ the integral must converge to $0$ since the integral of $(x-y)^n$ does.